# Как получить объект лежащий в TreeView и вывести его содержимое в ListView

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview

Разметка в MainWindow.xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TreeView
            Name="myTreeView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Levels}"
            SelectedValuePath="Name">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="child">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemTemplate="{StaticResource child}" ItemsSource="{Binding Subjects}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Предмет" />
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Описание" />
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
```

Класс Level

```
private string name;
    private List<Subject> subjects;

    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
    public List<Subject> Subjects { get { return subjects; } set { subjects = value; } }

    public Level() { }

    public Level(string name, List<Subject> subjects)
    {
        Name = name;
        Subjects = subjects;
    }
```

Класс

```
private string name;
    private string description;

    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
    public string Decsription { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }

    public Subject() { }

    public Subject(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Subject(string name, string description) :this(name)
    {
        Decsription = description;
    }
```

VM

```
private object selectedItem;

    private ObservableCollection<Level> levels;

    private RelayCommand showSelectedItem;

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedItem != value)
            {
                selectedItem = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Level> Levels { get { return levels; } set { levels = value; } }

    public MainViewViewModel()
    {
        Levels = new ObservableCollection<Level>()
        {
            new Level("Level 1", new List<Subject>
            {
                new Subject("Stage 1"),
                new Subject("Stage 2")
            }),
            new Level("Level 2", new List<Subject>
            {
                new Subject("Stage 1"),
                new Subject("Stage 2"),
                new Subject("Stage 3")
            })
        };
    }
```

Как вывести содержимое Subject в ListView, при выборе из TreeView?

Comment: `SelectedItem`?

Comment: SelectedItem readonly, его не забиндить

Comment: забиндить можно, но не в режиме двусторонней привязки, я по вопросу понял что вам нужен только вывод. Если еще и присвоение, то берите код отсюда - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000040/data-binding-to-selecteditem-in-a-wpf-treeview

Comment: Если проблема все еще не решена - дайте мне знать, если решена - предлагаю написать ответ

Comment: нашел. Спасибо.

Comment: попробуете написать ответ?

Comment: Помогла вот эта ссылка http://www.dotnetlead.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разметка в MainWindow.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
        <TreeView
            Name="tvMain"
            BorderThickness="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Levels}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Subjects}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tvMain, Path=SelectedItem}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TreeView>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader CommandParameter="Name" Content="Предмет" />
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader CommandParameter="Description" Content="Описание" />
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
```

Перед этим добавил в тег Window следующее

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Классы Level, Subject, Items

```
public class Level
{
    private string name;
    private ObservableCollection<Subject> subjects;

    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
    public ObservableCollection<Subject> Subjects { get { return subjects; } set { subjects = value; } }

    public Level() { }

    public Level(string name, ObservableCollection<Subject> subjects)
    {
        Name = name;
        Subjects = subjects;
    }
}
public class Subject
{
    private string name;
    private string description;
    private ObservableCollection<Items> items;

    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
    public string Decsription { get { return description; } set { description = value; } }

    public ObservableCollection<Items> Items { get { return items; } set { items = value; } }

    public Subject() { }

    public Subject(string name, ObservableCollection<Items> items)
    {
        Name = name;
        Items = items;
    }

    public Subject(string name, string description, ObservableCollection<Items> items) : this(name, items)
    {
        Decsription = description;
    }

    private bool selected;
    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return selected; }
        set
        {
            selected = value;
        }
    }
}
public class Items
{
    private string name;
    private string description;

    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
    public string Description { get { return description; } set { description = value; } }

    public Items() { }

    public Items(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Items(string name, string description) : this(name)
    {
        Description = description;
    }
}
```

Переделал RelayCommand (CustomRelayCommand)

```
public class CustomRelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _Execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _CanExecute;

    public CustomRelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {

    }

    public CustomRelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
    {
        _Execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("execute", "Execute cannot be null.");
        _CanExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _Execute(parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_CanExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _CanExecute(parameter);
    }
}
```

VM

```
public class MainViewViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Subject selectedSubject;

    private CustomRelayCommand selectedCommand;

    private ObservableCollection<Level> levels;

    private ObservableCollection<Items> selectedItems;

    public ObservableCollection<Level> Levels
    {
        get { return levels; }
        set { levels = value; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Items> SelectedItems
    {
        get { return selectedItems; }
        set { selectedItems = value; }
    }

    public Subject SelectedSubject
    {
        get { return selectedSubject; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                selectedSubject = value;
                selectedSubject.Selected = true;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Subject");
            }

        }
    }

    public CustomRelayCommand SelectedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (selectedCommand == null)
            {
                selectedCommand = new CustomRelayCommand(i => SetSelected(i), null);
            }
            return selectedCommand;
        }
    }

    private void SetSelected(object element)
    {
        Subject subject = SelectedSubject;
        SelectedSubject = element as Subject;
        if (subject != SelectedSubject)
        {
            SelectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (var item in SelectedSubject.Items)
            {
                SelectedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }

    }

    public MainViewViewModel()
    {
        SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<Items>();
        Levels = new ObservableCollection<Level>()
        {
            new Level("Level 1", new ObservableCollection<Subject>
            {
                new Subject("Stage1","Level 1", new ObservableCollection<Items>()
                {
                    new Items("Item 1", "description 1"),
                    new Items("Item 2", "description 2")
                }),
                new Subject("Stage 2","Level 1", new ObservableCollection<Items>()
                {
                    new Items("Item 3", "description 3")
                })
            }),
            new Level("Level 2", new ObservableCollection<Subject>
            {
                new Subject("Stage 1", "Level 2", new ObservableCollection<Items>()
                {
                    new Items("Item 4", "description 4"),
                    new Items("Item 5", "description 5"),
                    new Items("Item 6", "description 6"),
                    new Items("Item 7", "description 7")
                }),
                new Subject("Stage 2", "Level 2", new ObservableCollection<Items>()
                {
                    new Items("Item 8", "description 8"),
                    new Items("Item 9", "description 9"),
                    new Items("Item 1", "description 1")
                }),
                new Subject("Stage 3", "Level 2", new ObservableCollection<Items>()
                {
                    new Items("Item 2", "description 2"),
                    new Items("Item 3", "description 3")
                })
            })
        };
    }
}
```

Как то так...(много лишнего, наверно). Не уверен, что это лучший вариант, но работает.